# Альтернативная установка пакетов для Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Подскажите есть ли способ устанавливать пакеты через менеджер пакетов, но качать не с github, ибо его на работе заблочили сисадмины.
[image: к стандартному репозиторию даже не подключается]
[!][2]][2]

Comment: Ругайтесь с сисадминами, пока они вам и ruSO не заблочили ;-)

Comment: [**Использование Package Control через прокси**](https://www.laurivan.com/install-and-use-package-control-behind-proxy/). Спасибо.

Comment: хорошо, а как настроить прокси :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дома скачать нужные плагины с github и принести эту флешку на работу. 
Такой вариант не рассматриваться?

Comment: Да, так и решил проблему) только не плагины скачивал, а сам саблайм потрабл с установленными пакетами  закинул на флешку